# How to animate fragment from bottom

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, android-animation

I have an activity, I want to add the `Fragment` on activity then when i `click` a button `Fragment` should appear from bottom with animation .

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can add fragment in your activity in this way, add this part of code in you `onClick()` method:

```
FragmentTransaction mfragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

//add an animation, you can create your custom animation. Show below
mfragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
MFragment mFragment = new MFragment();
mfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MFragment, mFragment);
mfragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromXDelta="100%"
   android:toXDelta="0"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
   android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml

```
<set>
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromXDelta="-100%"
   android:toXDelta="0"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
   android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

This is an example that animate the fragments from left to right. You can play with xml values to change the animation direction as you want. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
       android:fromYDelta="75%p"
       android:toYDelta="0%p"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Translation through code

```
 TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 500); 
 anim.setDuration(200);
 balllayout.startAnimation(anim);
```

`balllayout` are the layout which is animated.